# CMake GLOB not returning any source files?

Tags: c++, cmake, glob

I am trying to automatically have my Makefiles written for my C++ project using CMake with `GLOB`. The code and headers are however located in two separate folders.

```
/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/ProjectName/Backend
```

and

```
/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/ProjectName/Terminal
```

The backend has platform independent code. Just a bunch of c and c++ source files. And the Terminal folder has some code that uses the objects specified in Backend to run some tests on them. The reason these are in separate folders is that the Backend code is Multiplatform. So an Xcode project imports it etc. The Terminal folder has the testing code because that is the only one that is trying to compile it into a linux binary.

Anywho, I have the following CMakeList.txt file that I am trying to build to generate the Makefile.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(terminalTest)

set(MainSource "/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/ProjectName/Backend")
set(TerminalSource "/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/ProjectName/Terminal")

#Bring the headers, such as Student.h into the project
include_directories(${MainSource} ${TerminalSource})

#Can manually add the sources using the set command as follows:
#set(SOURCES src/mainapp.cpp src/Student.cpp)

#However, the file(GLOB...) allows for wildcard additions:
file(GLOB SOURCES "./{${MainSource},${TerminalSource}}/*.cpp")

add_executable(terminalTest ${SOURCES})
```

And the result of this when I run this from the CMake GUI is a successful configure but an error `No SOURCES given to target: terminalTest` meaning that my `file()` command is not working properly.

I think it could have something to do with the fact that I have spaces in my paths but that doesn't seem to do it either. By the way I am putting this file in the Terminal folder and attempting to build from Terminal/Build.

Is there any way to debug and see what sources the `GLOB` command is bringing in? Can I actually do a multi directory `GLOB` like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`file(GLOB ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob) path looks malformed. You can list the paths to your sources separately in this command to grab all the source files in *both* directories.

```
file(GLOB SOURCES 
    ${MainSource}/*.cpp
    ${TerminalSource}/*.cpp
)
```